# How to create an angled 90 degree border with CSS?

Tags: css

For example, something like this:

[image: 90 degree border]

Is the only way of making this with pseudo elements?

Comment: You could use 3 HTML tags as well, if this is what you like.

Comment: You can create 2 pseudo-elements using `::after` and `::before` and set the desired height and width and background color, then set `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom` as `-10px` accordingly, it will give you the expected output. You might need to adjust the `z-index` as well.

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Nothing so far - I just have an image and I want it to have cornered borders like in the image

Comment: Have a go at coding this. Several ways to tackle it, pseudo  elements, background images, borders…If still stuck put the code you have directly into your question with a description of what isn’t working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible way to have the desired result using **1** element along with its `before` and `after` pseudo-elements.

```css
#fancy-borders {
  position: relative;
  /* very important */
  width: 150px;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  height: 150px;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  background-color: skyblue;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  margin: 10px auto;
  /* not required for the effect to work */
}

#fancy-borders:before,
#fancy-borders:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /** very important */
  width: 40%;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  height: 40%;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  background-color: purple;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  z-index: -1;
  /* place the pseudo elements behind the actual DIV */
}


/* pseudo-elements positionning */

#fancy-borders:before {
  bottom: -5px;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  left: -5px;
  /* change this per your requirement */
}

#fancy-borders:after {
  top: -5px;
  /* change this per your requirement */
  right: -5px;
  /* change this per your requirement */
}
```

```html
<div id="fancy-borders"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution with gradients and a few lines of code:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 5px solid #0000;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) padding-box,
   repeating-conic-gradient(blue 0 25%,#0000 0 50%) border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.box {
  /*make it relative so absolute elements can be within its boudry*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  /*half of the box*/
  height: 4px;
  background-color: black;
}


/*Settings postions for horizontal borders*/

.box::before {
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
}

.box::after {
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
}


/*working on vertical borders*/

.vertical-borders:before,
.vertical-borders:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  /*half of box*/
  width: 4px;
  background-color: black;
}


/*Settings postions for vertical borders*/

.vertical-borders:before {
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
}

.vertical-borders:after {
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="vertical-borders"></span>
</div>
```